# How to use HTTP Authentication with PHP and then run the entered data against a database?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, authentication

Creating simple php login scripts is easy, with simple one table mysql integration. I was wondering how i could you the rather snazzy HTTP Authentication that is available in HT Access and PHP, but the users are checked against a mysql database?

I am sure this is possible, but i have no idea how :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authentication data *(at least if using Basic mode)* should be available in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` *(see [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))* -- which means you "just" have to use those to check with your database.

Here's an article about that, for instance : [HTTP Basic and Digest authentication with PHP](http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/article/223)

Comment: So i would run the `isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])` and then check the sent http data against my database, then return this `header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');` if they are not allowed, or this (i dont know what to do) if they are :)

Comment: The "this I don't know what to do", you are the only one who can know : it's what users who have entered their credentials should be able to do ;-)

Comment: Ah is see, so if they are ok - then there is no need to pass over any HTTP header? :) cool!