# Basic auth (like apache's .htaccess) using php, how?

Tags: php

How can I implement basic auth using php? Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTTP Authentication with PHP and then run the entered data against a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000500/how-to-use-http-authentication-with-php-and-then-run-the-entered-data-against-a-d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP manual has an example of how to implement an [HTTP Basic authentication in PHP](http://php.net/features.http-auth)

P.S. http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+basic+auth

Comment: I hope you provide a little more information than just a link.

Comment: @Gumbo I doubt I can provide more than PHP team itself

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Not even something like “The PHP manual has an example of how to implement an [HTTP Basic authentication in PHP](http://php.net/features.http-auth) …”?

Comment: Col's well loved for providing to the point information concisely.

Comment: @Gumbo you know that race to be first :) English isn't my native, but PHP is. I typed this address by heart, quite fast. But these wordy explanation will take ages :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: But the five minutes time window should be enough to enhance a “two URLs” message to a “two URLs plus some bland words” message.

Comment: @Gumbo okay, if you want it official way. Let's close it and cut it off. There are tons of wordy answers already.